# Passing values back and forth appdomains

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, remoting, appdomain

I have the following code:

```
    public class AppDomainArgs : MarshalByRefObject {
        public string myString;
    }

    static AppDomainArgs ada = new AppDomainArgs() { myString = "abc" };

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Domain666");
        domain.DoCallBack(MyNewAppDomainMethod);
        Console.WriteLine(ada.myString);
        Console.ReadKey();
        AppDomain.Unload(domain);
    }

    static void MyNewAppDomainMethod() {
        ada.myString = "working!";
    }
```

I thought make this would make my ada.myString have "working!" on the main appdomain, but it doesn't. I thought that by inhering from MarshalByRefObject any changes made on the 2nd appdomain would reflect also in the original one(I thought this would be just a proxy to the real object on the main appdomain!)?

Thanks

Comment: (added a bit of explanation as a comment)

Comment: Also keep in mind that in order to pass an object across domains, it must be serializable. That leaves out many .NET objects, as I found after many wasted days.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you never actually pass the object over the boundary; thus you have **two** `ada` instances, one in each app-domain (the static field initializer runs on both app-domains). You will need to pass the instance over the boundary for the `MarshalByRefObject` magic to kick in.

For example:

```
using System;
class MyBoundaryObject : MarshalByRefObject {
    public void SomeMethod(AppDomainArgs ada) {
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName + "; executing");
        ada.myString = "working!";
    }
}
public class AppDomainArgs : MarshalByRefObject {
    public string myString { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
     static void Main() {
         AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Domain666");
         MyBoundaryObject boundary = (MyBoundaryObject)
              domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                 typeof(MyBoundaryObject).Assembly.FullName,
                 typeof(MyBoundaryObject).FullName);

         AppDomainArgs ada = new AppDomainArgs();
         ada.myString = "abc";
         Console.WriteLine("Before: " + ada.myString);
         boundary.SomeMethod(ada);
         Console.WriteLine("After: " + ada.myString);         
         Console.ReadKey();
         AppDomain.Unload(domain);
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand "How would be that?", but if you want an example; added.

Comment: I just run your code and it does what i am looking for! Thanks! Now I'll look at it carefully to understand what's happing in there.

Comment: The important points; I need a method (`SomeMethod`) that passes an instance of `AppDomainArgs` over the boundary; this method must *itself* be on a `MarshalByRefObject`, and we want the `MyBoundaryObject` object to be in the other app-domain (`CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`).

Comment: But what is the reason that my code, having both Main() and MyNewAppDomainMethod() refering to a global variable, don't actually refer to the same variable? Shouldn't it be the same than declaring the variable and passing it into the method, like you do in your MyBoudaryObject.SomeMethod()?

Comment: Better yet, is there any book where they explain well this boundary things, so I can understand the basis of this?

Comment: Simply; instance fields are scoped by the instance; static fields are scoped by the `AppDomain`. Your references to `ada` are actually "`ada` in the current app-domain" - which is different for the code in `Main` (executing on the primary app-domain) and `MyNewAppDomainMethod` (executing in `"Domain666"`). Re books - I don't know, sorry.

Comment: So having my myString property static won't help in anything, as MarshalByRefObject only applies to instance fields, right?

Comment: @Marc, or anyone else knowledgeable, would you mind taking a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100718/passing-collection-objects-back-and-forth-between-appdomains , and perhaps commenting on the situation.

Comment: @RenniePet does "don't expect arrays to keep in sync between app-domains" count as an answer?

Comment: @Marc, thanks, an answer, even a disclaimer, is always a bit more knowledge, and that's good. But do you have any suggestions for possible other (better?) workarounds than the answer on that thread? If not, thanks again.

Comment: @RenniePet not really, no. IMO, when working with app-domains, the easiest-to-keep-sane approach is to treat it as message passing - so the only bridges are discreet "this sent me a message, which I can process". In most of my implementations, I try to keep it so that the **only** code that even knows there are two domains is a simple message send/receive handler. Beyond that: I treat them as if they were entirely separate. Most of the headaches go away if you keep it really really simple.